# Redirect to another page with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a Javascript array in page 1 and i need it in page 2.

I tried with JQuery post method but i couldn't make it work :

```
   $.post( "{{path('result')}}", mydata );
```

How do i properly redirect the user from page 1 to page 2 with that array ?

Are cookies or sessions useful in this case ?

I'm using Symfony4 with Twig.

Thank you.

Comment: can you include mydata code?

Comment: Hi, i didn't code it yet, it's supposed to be a javascript array.
I tried this :  $.post( "{{path('result')}}"); and i couldn't make it work. So i'll actually put the data after i succeed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to post your data to page 1 using jQuery post(). Then in the page 1 controller action, you will need to redirect to page 2 controller. You can have a look at this link (https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html)

```
public function index($name)
{
    $response = $this->forward('App\Controller\OtherController::fancy', [
        'name'  => $name,
        'color' => 'green',
    ]);

    // ... further modify the response or return it directly

    return $response;
}

public function fancy($name, $color)
{
    // ... create and return a Response object
}
```